# Cytoscape TypeError: l is undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, json, cytoscape.js

I am developing a cytoscape graph in C# asp.net and I have a very strange problem.
I'm using the JSON data below:

```json
[
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "15",
            "name": "Low rainfall",
            "href": "/Test?id1=15",
            "colour": "#ff9933",
            "shape": "ellipse"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "16",
            "name": "Climate change",
            "href": "/Test?id1=16",
            "colour": "#ff9933",
            "shape": "ellipse"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "17",
            "name": "Drought",
            "href": "/Test?id1==17",
            "colour": "#ff9933",
            "shape": "ellipse"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "18",
            "name": "human deaths",
            "href": "/Test?id1=18",
            "colour": "#ff9933",
            "shape": "ellipse"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "19",
            "name": "Global warming",
            "href": "/Test?id1=19",
            "colour": "#ff9933",
            "shape": "ellipse"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "source": "19",
            "target": "16",
            "label": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "source": "16",
            "target": "17",
            "label": "14"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "source": "15",
            "target": "16",
            "label": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "source": "16",
            "target": "15",
            "label": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "source": "15",
            "target": "17",
            "label": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "source": "18",
            "target": "17",
            "label": "31"
        }
    }
]
```

This gives the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: l is undefined
q https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
j https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
run https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
promise callback*$a/< https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
$a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
hl https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
<anonymous> https://localhost:44391/graph:135
EventListener.handleEvent* https://localhost:44391/graph:133
cytoscape.min.js:32:66425
q https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
j https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
comparefn self-hosted:203
InsertionSort self-hosted:4426
MergeSort self-hosted:4478
sort self-hosted:191
run https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
(Async: promise callback)
a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
$a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
hl https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
<anonymous> https://localhost:44391/graph:135
(Async: EventListener.handleEvent)
<anonymous> https://localhost:44391/graph:133
```

line 133 in graph is:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
```

line 135 is:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),  // line 136
```

If I remove the line

```json
{
    "data": {
        "source": "15",
        "target": "17",
        "label": "2"
    }
}
```

It works fine.

It might be something to do with the fact that 15 goes to 16 and 16 goes to 17 therefore 15 cannot go to 17?! Though I have tried a similar arrangement in earlier testing with no issues.
I’m using `cytoscape.min.js` and `cytoscape-cxtmenu.js` and the app is a web site.
For the layout I’m using, `breadthfirst` and the root is #15; if I change the root to 16, it still errors but with fewer references:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: l is undefined
q https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
j https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
run https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
a https://localhost:44391/js/cytoscape.min.js:32
```

All very strange.

Comment: I have just imported the data into an old html set up, so I can fiddle with the numbers and have found that if I set the roots as #17 or #18 it works - but not if I set roots as #15, #16 or #19. So it looks like a roots issue?

Comment: I have resolved this by using the cola layout. - https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-cola/
I couldn't get my head round the rules for breadthfirst

Comment: I think the breadthfirst layout is suited best for trees and forrests, not common graphs. You have nodes with cyclic relations, so maybe that is the problem? Cola seems to be a good compromise though.

Comment: I think you are right @StephanT  - whilst my graph is hierarchical it most definitely isn't a tree as It can have many "roots". Funnily the "random" layout is pretty good too - though sometimes a bit too random :) I now have ```layout: {
 name: 'cola',
 nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: true,
        randomize: true, 
        padding: 5
 }```  which works pretty well. Users have the option to re-randomize a cola layout.

Comment: @StephanT. - Thanks - still getting used to the idiosyncrasies of Stackoverflow's markdown rules ;) I see that name mention didn't work either.